# Print big number in hexadecimal

Tags: r, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert big number to hexadecimal representation in R, but it fails, because it can't fit into 32-bit integer. Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

```
> print(0xffffffff+0x10000000)
[1] 4563402751
> as.hexmode(0xffffffff+0x10000000)
Error in if (is.double(x) && (x == as.integer(x))) x <- as.integer(x) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In as.hexmode(4294967295 + 268435456) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily I found the solution, but requires library gmp

```
library(gmp)
> as.character(as.bigz(0xffffffff+0x10000000),b=16)
[1] "10fffffff"
```